# RxJava and Retrofit2: NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I realize that I am using subscribeOn()/observeOn() on the MainThread.
What are the set of options I can pass into subscribeOn()?
What are the set of options I can pass into observeOn()?

```
12-17 21:36:09.154 20550-20550/rx.test D/MainActivity2: [onCreate]
12-17 21:36:09.231 20550-20550/rx.test D/MainActivity2: starting up observable...
12-17 21:36:09.256 20550-20550/rx.test D/MainActivity2: [onError] 
12-17 21:36:09.256 20550-20550/rx.test W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

**GovService.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import retrofit.Call;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import rx.Observable;

public interface GovService {
    @GET("/txt2lrn/sat/index_1.json")
    Observable<MyTest> getOneTestRx();
}
```

**MyTest.java**

```
public class MyTest {
    private String name, url;
    private int num;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + this.name + ", num: " + this.num + ", url: " + this.url;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity2.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;

import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit.Retrofit;
import retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "[onCreate]");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        RecyclerView mRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        mRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));// setup LayoutManager
        mRV.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());// setup ItemAnimator

        // setup retrofit
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://goanuj.freeshell.org")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
        GovService service = retrofit.create(GovService.class);

        Log.d(TAG, "starting up observable...");
        Observable<MyTest> o = service.getOneTestRx();
        o.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
        o.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
        o.subscribe(new Subscriber<MyTest>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.d(TAG, "[onCompleted] ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "[onError] ");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(MyTest m) {
                Log.d(TAG, "[onNext] " + m.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: try to do `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`. this will execute Observable  in New Thread.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Rewrite the last part of your code to:

```
service.getOneTestRx()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<MyTest>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "[onCompleted] ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "[onError] ");
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(MyTest m) {
            Log.d(TAG, "[onNext] " + m.toString());
        }
    });
```

**Important note** from @akarnokd:

> Worth mentioning that one needs to chain the calls as here because
>   Observable is not the builder pattern (where you modify the settings
>   of an existing object)

Comment: Worth mentioning that one needs to chain the calls as here because Observable is not the builder pattern (where you modify the settings of an existing object).

Comment: Explanation is also worth mentionng. Why should OP rewrite like this, why is your variant correct? I'm not asking for myself. A good answer should have this.

Comment: Any idea how to do this with RxJava 2?

Answer (score 8):

You should call `Observable.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())`, `retrofit` will unsubscribe at the end of a http-request.

In `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory` of `retrofit-rxjava-adapter`

it actions like this.

```
if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
    subscriber.onCompleted();
}
```

But when `subscriber` is a `SafeSubscriber`, it'll call `unsubscribe` finally.

I have this issue in my app.

Full code:

```
o.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
```

Comment: yep, that's the solution here too: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1328 - this will apparently be fixed in the release version of retrofit 2, after okhttp 2.7 comes out (which it already came out).

Comment: @ahmedre they never will... `That's not a Retrofit or OkHttp problem`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createAsync()` with your `Retrofit` builder will resolve the issue and it creates asynchronous observables.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                       .client(client) 
                       .baseUrl(httpsUrl) 
                       .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)
                       .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.createAsync()) 
                       .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) 
                       .build();
```