# How to create Asynchronous Call using Retrofit and Observables in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to make API calls using Retrofit2 library, returns generic type observable.

I am getting an error: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, while making calls.

Comment: subscribe on another thread.

Comment: *to make return type generic I am using observables* - that's not what observables are for

Comment: Please consider to accept the response if helped you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks really easy to solve, **two cases to consider.** :1)If you are not using RXJava or 2) if you are using it

> **1) If you are NOT using RXJava**

You should use the method [enqueue](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-) when you make the call. The error you get is because you are calling the response on the same Thread(the MainThread)

Here is an example took from the web that uses Enqueue with Kotlin that possibly you can adapt to your case

```
override fun loadPokemonList(pokemonListListener: PokemonListListener) {


    call = pokemonService.getPokedex();
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<PokeDex> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<PokeDex>?, response: Response<PokeDex>?) {

            if (response != null && response.isSuccessful) {
                pokemonListListener.onSuccess(response.body())
            } else {
                pokemonListListener.onFailure(appContext.getString(R.string.error_fetching_data))
            }


        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<PokeDex>?, t: Throwable?) {
            pokemonListListener.onFailure(appContext.getString(R.string.error_fetching_data))
        }
    })


 }
```

> **2) If you are using RXJava**(usually version 2, be aware you will find several tutorials for the first version online)

But please consider that most of the developers today solve this asynchronous call using RXJava2 that is the second case I was mentioning at the beginning of he post. **It will take you several hours to understand the basics** of it but once you will do, you will have a great skill to bring with you and manage this kind of calls( even multiple ones) will be really simple. In fact RXJava allows you really easy to direct the operation in a concurrent Thread and observe the result on the Main Thread. Here a good tutorial that explains how to [do that](https://medium.com/3xplore/handling-api-calls-using-retrofit-2-and-rxjava-2-1871c891b6ae)
with the easy and well known pattern (see the notations)

```
Observable<List<TrendsResponse>>
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())//Run the call on another Thread
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())//observe on the Main Thread
    .subscribe();
```

Differently by what people new to RXJava think:
 ***on default RXJava does not call a concurrent Thread***, is up to you to do that with the `subcribeOn` that does all the "dirty" work and then to observe the result on the Main Thread with `ObserveOn`.

For principiants is easy to grasp that comparing both of them to the two famous methods of AsyncTask: `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute`

EDIT: Please look also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349334/rxjava-and-retrofit2-networkonmainthreadexception) if you or future users have problems.

Comment: I have my api call as :
@GET("/path/to/the/end/point")
fun getDataFromAPI(@QueryMap paramenters: HashMap<String,String>): Observable<ReturnType>

Not getting call to enqueue .

Comment: OK so you are using RXJava because you have  an `Observable`! when you getDataFromAPI add the two lines showed above `subscribeOn` and `ObserveOn`. It will work, if you have problems study the tutorial enclosed is great for learning purposes.

Comment: Thanks, Trocchietto!

Comment: you are really welcome @s.thakur please consider also the link I edited at end, somebody had your same problem, read the post

Comment: Which library version should I use to get "import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers". 
I am using "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1" (which doens't have rx.android)

Comment: @s.thakur good question at the moment I am using these two    `implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'` and to come back to your question this one
`implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'` that will give you AndroidSchedulers  (please note that you could substitute implementation with compile if your version of AStudio is < than 3.0

Answer (score 1):

With Retrofit/RxJava, the network call will be default be performed on the thread that subscribes to the Observable returned from the stub. On Android, we are normally executing on the "main" thread, and it is not permitted to access the network on this thread, hence the error.

The solution is to tell RxJava to subscribe to the Observable on a different thread:

```
getDataFromAPI(/*...*/)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observerOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe({ /* result available in `it` */ })
```

`Schedulers.io()` is a reference to a scheduler that uses a set of threads specifically intended to be used for IO operations.

The `.observeOn` allows you to handle the result safely back on the main thread.

Comment: I am getting error when trying to add AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() ? I am using io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava.2.x.x and io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.x.x.

Comment: @s.thakur Make sure you don't have another (1.x?) version of rxandroid included, and that the import is coming from `import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;`